# no RTTI on unamed data types

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, rtti

AFAIK the compiler does not generate RTTI if the type is not named.
eg: T = array[0..1,0..1] of Integer;
In this case it is possible to know the total size of the array, but it is impossible to know the size of each dimension.

It works only if I use a type explicitly named:
T01 = 0..1;
T = array[T01,T01] of Integer;

I missed something?

Test code:

```
type
  t = array[0..1, 0..1] of Integer;

procedure test;
var
  i: PTypeInfo;
  d: TArrayTypeData;
begin
  i := TypeInfo(t);
  assert(i.Kind = tkArray);
  d := GetTypeData(i).ArrayData;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is currently limitation of the RTTI information generated, you must have a type name.

Things like this will not work:

```
var
 StrArray :  Array of String;
```

But the following will work:

```
type
  TStrArray = Array of String;
var
  StrArray : TStrArray;
```

I typically have switched my switched my dynamic arrays to use the new syntax of
TArray which is defined in the system.pas unit as, to make sure they do have names.

`TArray<T> = array of T;`

So a workaround to your specific problem would be to declare a type name for that array.

```
type
  TMyArray = array[0..1, 0..1] of Integer;
var
  t : TMyArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still get array dimensions using builtins `High` and `Low`. Let's take the example type `array[0..1,3..4] of Integer`:

```
Low(T) // low bound of first range (0)
High(T) // high bound of first range (1)
Low(T[Low(T)]) // low bound of second range (3)
High(T[Low(T)]) // high bound of second range (4)
```

In the latter two, you can use any valid index in the index value.

Comment: I talking about new RTTI in Delphi 2010 ...
are you sure you understood my question ?

Comment: @Henri: I did, what I imply is that you don't need RTTI for this task. If you insist on the RTTI interface (why?), then I don't have an idea.

Comment: because I'm the author of superobject, the json parser:
http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6
I use RTTI to automatically serialize native types to json.

Comment: For array types to get RTTI (using typinfo unit) you can only use dynamic arrays (tkDynArray). All other array types are off.

Comment: "tkArray" is available and works, i added a test code in my question